# How to get the number of rows of the selected result from sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, count

I want to get the number of selected rows as well as the selected data. At the present I have to use two sql statements:

one is

```
select * from XXX where XXX;
```

the other is

```
select count(*) from XXX where XXX;
```

Can it be realised with a single sql string?

I've checked the source code of sqlite3, and I found the function of `sqlite3_changes()`. But the function is only useful when the database is changed (after `insert, delete or update`).

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Although the answer is yes, most of the answers below add complexity you should avoid. There is nothing wrong with running two queries. If you're processing the data after the query, you can also use `count()` or `size()` methods of your resulting collection object, depending on the language you're using.

Comment: I make a query, then turn each row into a C++ object and add the rows to a C++ std::vector. Obviously I want to do this as efficiently as possible. And adding items to a std::vector is significantly faster if you first reserve space for the right number of items. So making a query first to get the count is pointless because it is more efficient than my savings from knowing the count, and querying my std::vector at the end is also pointless because that's too late to help.

Answer (score 16):

try this way

```
select (select count() from XXX) as count, * 
from XXX;
```

Comment: The first line by itself worked for me "select (select count() from XXX) as count;" ... Thanks.

Comment: The first line is overly complex if you expect to get the count of rows. Just do "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM xxx;".

Answer (score 15):

SQL can't mix single-row (counting) and multi-row results (selecting data from your tables). This is a common problem with returning huge amounts of data. Here are some tips how to handle this:

- Read the first N rows and tell the user "more than N rows available". Not very precise but often good enough. If you keep the cursor open, you can fetch more data when the user hits the bottom of the view (Google Reader does this)
- Instead of selecting the data directly, first copy it into a temporary table. The INSERT statement will return the number of rows copied. Later, you can use the data in the temporary table to display the data. You can add a "row number" to this temporary table to make paging more simple.
- Fetch the data in a background thread. This allows the user to use your application while the data grid or table fills with more data.

Answer (score 2):

```
select (select COUNT(0) 
            from xxx t1 
            where t1.b <= t2.b 
            ) as 'Row Number', b from xxx t2 ORDER BY b;
```

just try [this](http://old.nabble.com/sequential-row-numbers-from-query-td22746903.html).

Comment: This actually adds an index to your output rows, but does not count the rows (until you've reached the last row) which is no better than "SELECT * FROM xxx;" and counting the number of sqlite3_row() returning SQLITE3_ROW, and it also sort your output which might be unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine them into a single statement:

```
select count(*), * from XXX where XXX
```

or

```
select count(*) as MYCOUNT, * from XXX where XXX
```

Comment: this only returns row count and only the last row.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of unique titles, you need to pass the DISTINCT clause to the COUNT function as the following statement:

```
SELECT
 COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)
FROM
 'table_name';
```

Source: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-count-function/

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for another method, the more elegant one I found to get the total of row was to use a CTE.
this ensure that the count is only calculated once :

```
WITH cnt(total) as (SELECT COUNT(*) from xxx) select * from xxx,cnt
```

the only drawback is if a WHERE clause is needed, it should be applied in both main query and CTE query.

In the first comment, Alttag said that there is no issue to run 2 queries. I don't agree with that unless both are part of a unique transaction. If not, the source table can be altered between the 2 queries by any INSERT or DELETE from another thread/process. In such case, the count value might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Once you already have the `select * from XXX` results, you can just find the array length in your program right?

Comment: I can. But only until I go through all the result rows. I want to get the count as quickly as possible

Comment: In that case, I guess running two SQL queries really is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`sqlite3_get_table`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html) instead of prepare/step/finalize you will get all the results at once in an array ("result table"), including the numbers and names of columns, and the number of rows. Then you should free the result with `sqlite3_free_table`

Comment: So, if you have 9 billions rows, you expect to fill your complete memory and hard drive just to know how many rows you have ? This is even worse than doing a for loop with count += sqlite3_step() == SQLITE3_ROW;

Comment: The linked page says "This is a legacy interface that is preserved for backwards compatibility. Use of this interface is not recommended."

Comment: No need to be that extreme dudes. SQLite is often used to read configuration information, where the number of rows of any table is not expected to be that big. This function must be used with care but still useful when you know what you do.

Comment: Also note, "not recommended" != "deprecated"

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can know the number of records generated by the query simply like this

```
command = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (name1)=? and (name2)=? ....."
cursor.execute(command, (aaaaa,bbbb,........))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
record_number = len (rows)
```

If the number is greater than zero it will be possible to access the data of the individual fields using a query of the type

k = rows[a][b]

where the value of 'a' represents the number of the record to be accessed and the value of 'b' represents the position of the field you want to acquire