# sqlite3_step and number of results

Tags: c++, sqlite, stdvector

After I do a `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` of a statement, then I need to `sqlite3_step()` it.

For the moment, let's ignore all return values except `SQLITE3_ROW` and `SQLITE3_DONE`.

As long as the return value of `sqlite3_step()` is `SQLITE3_ROW`, I need to keep calling it, till I get all the results. Then the last return value would be `SQLITE3_DONE`.

I'm entering my results into a `std::vector` using `push_back()`.

From what I've read, this should have an average complexity of O(log(n)) due to the resizing of the internal array of the vector. In order to reduce this complexity to O(1), I need to use `reserve()` of vector, before doing `push_back()`.

But then from the sqlite3 API, I can't see a function that returns the total number of results that I would get, before I `sqlite3_step()` it.

How can I do this with sqlite3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: did you benchmark it? Is this the bottleneck? If no, then just stop worrying about efficiency and complexity **now,** and `goto end of answer`.

Still here? OK, so let me tell you one more thing: resizing the vector may be of any complexity, it's up to the implementor of the C++ standard library. It may be `O(1)`, `O(n)`, `O(log n)`, etc. But one thing is sure: if you have got N results from the database, **you ain't no going to retrieve the data in `O(n)`.** Simply because you have... N results.

So I think that you should still not worry about this - `vector` is **fast** (assuming a reasonably high-quality standard library implementation). So go ahead and write that `while` loop and `push_back()` the elements one after another and that's it.

**But, if you are still being scared by the slowness of poor old vector,** then here's how you find the number of rows returned from a query - this is specific to SQLite:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM the_table WHERE some_condition;
```

Also, there are a few more possibilities, as described in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601600/how-to-get-the-number-of-rows-of-the-selected-result-from-sqlite3).

Comment: No. This is not the bottleneck and doing a `SELECT COUNT` and then a `reserve()` is probably slower than just doing `push_back()` without `reserve()`. I'm using the GNU STL.

Comment: I was just wondering if there's an inexpensive way to find out the number of results, so that I can do my micro-optimization, but if `SELECT COUNT` is the only way, then that's too expensive for my purposes because it would do an additional compilation of another SQL query. And yes, I know that there's no need to over-optimize where unnecessary.

Comment: @ruben2020 Very good. Then, you take the jump at the `goto` instruction :)