# SQLite vs MySQL ->rowCount()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sqlite

I'm working on a CRUD class that shoulde ease my work.
Now i'm trying to make it work with "SQlite" and "MySQL".
The CRUD for MySQL works without problems, but ever since i'm trying to get data from the SQLite database it making my life hard :).

The code below is the working MySQL CRUD function for getting everything from a given table.

```
public function getAll($table){        
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()){
        $item = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $item;
    }


    return false;
}
```

If i try the function from above on the SQLite database it doenst return anything.

However when i alter the code it does return the requested items.
The function below works for the SQLite database but there is very litle of verification.

```
public function getAll($table){        
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
    $stmt->execute();

    $items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $items;

}
```

So my conclusion is that the rowCount() function doesn't work for SQLite.
How can i solve this so that the SQLite CRUD first goes for a look if anything is truly returnd  ?
If its returnd , i can return the items.
If the rows ar empty it should return false .

Hope you guys understand what i'm trying to tell.

Best regards

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601600/how-to-get-the-number-of-rows-of-the-selected-result-from-sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowCount()` is only really safe to use on MySQL and a few others. It doesn't work well with portable applications like SQLite.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Comment: So might it be better just working with a try/catch method ? Or is there any other way to verify if truly somthing is returned ?

Comment: @JochemHoltackers do `$item = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); if($item && count($item)){ /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: Worked like a charm ! thanks for the help!

Comment: @JochemHoltackers, great! if i helpf please consider hitting the check mark by my answer.