# SQLite3 count rows

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to count the number of rows returned from a query

This is currently the code I have

```
function products()
{
$loggedin = loggedin();
$db = db();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT game_id, name, developer, price FROM game   WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY game_id DESC');
$result = $stmt->execute();
$row1 = $result->fetchArray();
$rows = count ($row1); 

if ($rows == 0)
    {
    echo "Sold out";
    }
else
    {
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['name'].'</p>';

    }
    }
}
```

At present it will only return the first item in the table, even though all rows match

if I change my code to

```
function products()
{
$loggedin = loggedin();
#$page = 'index.php';
$db = db();
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT game_id, name, developer, price FROM game   WHERE quantity > 11 ORDER BY game_id DESC');
$result = $stmt->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['name'].'</p>';

}
```

Then I get all the result from the table correctly

if I change the query to a value outside the quantity like

```
quantity > 20
```

then I get the error

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

what I would like it to do is if row1 is == 0 the show sold out other wise display all the rows

so if a row does not match the query it will not be included in the results 
I can not use PDO, and I have not been able to find out to use count on https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Comment: You get a warning and not an error, but it seems to work no?

Comment: fetchArray fetches one single record from the result set, so what you are trying to count there in the first snippet makes little sense to begin with - that is never going to result in more than 1. You should be using https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.numcolumns.php

Comment: @txemsukr Just noticed I made a mistake in my code as I was testing, will fix that up now, it is only returning the warning

Comment: @04FS thanks will try with numcolumns, so that will count all the rows in the column in the database?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php#94873

Comment: You can use numcolumns if you just need to determine whether you got any rows, or not. If you need the actual count - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601600/how-to-get-the-number-of-rows-of-the-selected-result-from-sqlite3

Comment: @u_mulder using     if ($result->numColumns() && $result->columnType(0) != SQLITE3_NULL) 
{ 
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
 echo '<p>'.$row['name'].'</p>';
}
}
else
{
echo "Sold out";
} that returns sold out only no matter what I change query to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it.

```
function products() {
    $loggedin = loggedin();
    $db = db();
    $games = $db->query('SELECT game_id, name, developer, price FROM game WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY game_id DESC');

    if (empty($games->fetchArray())) {
        echo "Sold out";
        return;
    }

    // Reset the result back to the first game
    $games->reset();

    while ($game = $games->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<p>'.$game['name'].'</p>';  
    }
}
```

Comment: OK if the is set to quantity > 20 I get sold out as expect, changing that to quantity > 0 I get  Illegal string offset 'name' for the rows, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php

Comment: if I change  code  foreach($games as $game) {
             echo '<p>'.$games['name'].'</p>'; it prints the last item for the total amount of rows

Comment: @Ausghostdog my bad, can't test my code right now. I edited my answer, does it work now?

Comment: Call to undefined function sqlite_num_rows, I am working with sqlite3

Comment: @Ausghostdog okay, edited it again. What about now?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
function products() {
    $db = db();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT game_id, name, developer, price FROM game WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY game_id DESC');
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $count = 0;

    while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
        echo '<p>'.$row['name'].'</p>';
        $count++;  
    }

    if ($count == 0) {
        echo "<p>Sold out</p>";
    }
}
```

The only way to find out how many rows were returned by a query is to fetch all of them (and you don't actually care how many rows were returned, just that at least one was). So just increment a counter once per row returned, and after stepping through all rows, if that counter is still 0, it means no rows were returned, and you can display the relevant message.